# Oxygen-carrying vascular nanobots

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, hard-science, health

People in my setting can have artificial red blood cells (they're nanobots or something similar). These are designed to fulfill the same role as regular red blood cells but have a much higher oxygen carrying capacity.

I expect people with these artificial red blood cells to have:

- A greatly increased breath-holding time (extended underwater dives)
- Superior stamina/takes longer for them to get winded

Questions:

- How much oxygen could a single artificial cell hold (2x a regular cell, 10x, 100x?) before we reach biological/chemical/physical/mechanical limits
- How long could an individual stay underwater while holding their breath with these blood cells before other biological limiters start coming into effect (carbon dioxide buildup?)
- How much longer could individuals with these blood cells run before they hit non-oxygen related biological limits?

Comment: How can we answer if you tell us nothing about how these things are made? It's like you are asking "how fast can a car go?" without telling us if the car is a corvette or a civic...

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica How they're made is handwaved in this case. I'm looking for limits. For example, I imagine that compressing oxygen enough for it to liquefy would be "too much" for human biology to be able to use. For example, if a single artificial cell can hold 1000x the oxygen of a regular cell (at the same size), I imagine that the human would simply pop when this oxygen is released at the delivery site. To match your analogy, I'm asking for the fastest land vehicle. I don't care if it's a corvette or a civic, as long as it's still eligible for the land-vehicle speed record.

Comment: They're not going to have superior stamina, for one. Stamina isn't a problem with the oxygen fluctuations in your body - it's a function of energy depletion and waste product buildup, which will only be sped up by the surplus of oxygen.

Comment: [Artificial blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_substitute) is a real thing and a subject of very intense research...

Comment: @Halfthawed Lactic acid builds up when the oxygen supply is limited and is a cause of fatigue. Sure, glucose limits and breakdown speed still affect stamina but someone who is breathing a higher o2 content air will have longer endurance/stamina

Comment: Anything you want. I think this question is backwards and makes no sense atm. Please state where you want to go with this. Unless your world building approach is complete chaos, you maybe have something in mind with this. Do you want people to hold their breath for a day or so in your world? Ask if this can be done with artificial blood. To revisit the fastest land vehicle: the speed is arbitrary, tell us how fast you want to go. Btw, please also state your education. If you have a ph.d. in a natural science, the scopes completely different than if you have no education in the field at all

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Biological systems tend to be low efficiency, so I could believe 10x easily.  There is a catch: What powers the nanobots?  Without a good power source, I might find 1x hard to believe.  I would consider any type of scavenged power to be poor.  With a particularly good power source, the nanites might convert carbon-dioxide into oxygen and accumulate or recombine the carbon.

Q2: Presumably, the artificial blood would also deal with carbon-dioxide.  Assuming it does, the other question becomes how much oxygen it is willing to give up.  If it holds 10x what normal blood hold, but won't be reduced below 7x, then it effectively functions as 3x.

Q3: I can't help you there.  I suggest looking for research on athletes in oxygen enriched environments.

Comment: If you can efficiently reduce CO2 in your nanomechanisms, then you can skip the whole inconvenient "breathing" thing.

Answer (score 1):

**1. By a factor of one, that's the biological limit.**

**2. None, it's a factor of one, unless you design them that way.**

**3. Not any longer than otherwise if all you've done is replace blood cells.**

So, let's discuss this. You've somehow manage to turn off the bone marrow in a human body in order to stop the production of red blood cells because you want to put in artificial red blood cell. Fine. But here's the thing - you're not going to have your blood cells *transport* oxygen anymore efficiently, because the human body isn't equipped to handle that. Balance of factors, reagents, and catalysts is a delicately controlled process and if your body screws it up, you die. And oxygen in particular is *horribly* reactive, so supplying your mitochondria with more oxygen than they normally handle isn't a great idea. Sure, you can use it to speed up the energy making process, but in general, that isn't needed and if you do it by a significant margin, let's say doubling the amount of available oxygen in the matrix, than bad things are going to happen. I don't know what bad things, I can only guess, but my guess is that the ATP producing subroutine goes out of whack, and since that is responsible for fueling energy to the vast majority of reactions that occur in your body, safe to say that it's a bad idea.

Now, like I said, you're not going to want to transport oxygen faster. But you can design these things to hold more oxygen and dole them out in the event of an emergency, if need be, though as I'm not a nano-engineer, I can only guess at the amount of oxygen you can fit in, because the limit is the method used to keep the surplus oxygen from leaking out all over the cell. The carbon dioxide buildup can actually just be solved by exhaling from your lungs, which will have the lungs collect more CO2, though I suspect that will require training as exhaling while you're drowning isn't what most people would consider a natural behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect people with these artificial red blood cells to have:
>
> - A greatly increased breath-holding time (extended underwater dives)
> - Superior stamina/takes longer for them to get winded

You should take care to distinguish oxygen *transport* from oxygen *storage*. In most vertebrates and almost all mammals, the latter task is handled by [myoglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoglobin) which you'll find in muscle tissue, not blood cells. That's not to say that artificial red cells couldn't also be highly effective oxygen stores, but it is worth remembering that there's more than one solution to this problem. Whales and walruses can dive for extremely extended periods of time without magical technologies.

> How much oxygen could a single artificial cell hold (2x a regular cell, 10x, 100x?) before we reach biological/chemical/physical/mechanical limits

So long as there was a sensible mechanism for releasing enough oxygen to satisfy demand, you could have each of your artificial red cells basically store liquid oxygen. The problem then is one of *safety*. Anything that causes your oxygen-bearers to rupture is going to cause [gas embolisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_embolism) and, at worst, render their owner [highly flammable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_human_combustion). Actually *loading* your cells with oxygen will be the tricky bit, as you'll need to have some kind of powered system if you want anything more effective than the concentration gradient diffusion mechanism that normal red blood cells use. Once you've made your red cells active partipants in the process, you now need to worry about powering them, too, and their own metabolism will reduce the efficiency of your system and produce its own waste products.

> How long could an individual stay underwater while holding their breath with these blood cells before other biological limiters start coming into effect (carbon dioxide buildup?)

Obviously, that largely depends on how much oxygen you've handwaved into your artificial cells, so I can't give you any figures here. "Normal" (by which I mean unmodified but exceptional) humans can hold their breath for ten minutes, so that should be readily achievable. Any more than that is up to you.

The carbon dioxide issue however could be worked around to some degree. Normal haemoglobin can bind CO<sub>2</sub>, forming [carbaminohaemoglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbaminohemoglobin). In humans, most (~70%) carbon dioxide ends up in blood plasma in the form of bicarbonate, but so long as your artificial cells keep blood pH in sensible limits perhaps they could bind more carbon dioxide. [Crocodile haemoglobin](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/23111643_CO2_governs_the_oxygen_affinity_of_crocodile_blood) is also stimulated to release *more* of the carried oxygen in the presence of bicarbonate, unlike the human equivalent which won't give up nearly as much under normal circumstances, one way of improving cellular oxygen supply without needing to store additional oxygen per cell.

> How much longer could individuals with these blood cells run before they hit non-oxygen related biological limits?

The three obvious issues are lactate buildup from anaerobic respiration, carbon dioxide buildup from aerobic respiration and cellular energy reserves. I've already looked at carbon dioxide. It isn't clear how well your cells would deal with lactate buildup... if you want to reduce anaerobic metabolism in muscle cells, you'd want to take a look at improving oxygen storage in those cells, and you're not doing that.

I guess the best thing to do would be to look at which sports have had issues with [erythropoietin doping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythropoietin#Usage_as_doping_product). Interestingly, use of the drug does not seem to help amateurs too much, suggesting that maybe your super blood *alone* will not turn users into superhumans, but they'll need a decent level of physical fitness to make the most of it. They'd be able to cycle like Lance Armstrong with a bit of effort, I'm sure.